# Does Shri Yantra really increases wealth? If so, how to use it and what are the vidhi-nishedhas?

Tags: rituals, worship, lakshmi, sri-vidya, yantra

What are the methods of using Shri Yantra? Can I, a Kshatriya by nature, worship it? What are the thing to avoid? Also can you mention where can I find elaborate information regarding these?

[image: an image of Sri yantra]

Comment: Sri Yantra is known as the Chakra Raja (the king of all Yantras). Presiding deity is Lalita Tripurasundari and she gives Moksha and all other Chaturvargas not just wealth.The Sadhana of Sri Yantra is known as Sri Vidya and it has to be learned from a Guru. If however you want to simply keep this Yantra then place it on an altar on a red cloth and offer  dhup,deepa, flowers etc.to it.Place it in the north east corner of the room. A more detailed worship of Sri Chakra is complicated (Known as Navavarana Puja) and it has to be learned from one's Guru.

Comment: @Rickross Can I not learn it from any scripture? Also, offering dhup & Deepa will not be enough will it?

Comment: You can not or rather should not learn the detailed Puja from internet. Yes,offering Dhupa,Deepa will be enough for the goal in mind.

Comment: @Rickross I hardly think I would find any Guru who would know these arts nowadays. Gurus these days only know Vedanta and Bhagavata. Rest of them are Pauranika kathavachakas. So, my only hope is an authentic scripture.

Comment: By reading scriptures we ourselves can not learn Sri Vidya. Learning Gita, Vedanta is one thing but this is more complicated. And you can find Gurus if you search heard. Check manblunder website and contact them.